# add textfields and delete textfields with dynamic delete button

Tags: jquery

I have two functions 'add' and 'delete'. I have a limit of adding 15 input text fields for which I have a counter. now I have to delete the fields as well to reduce the counter value. I have dynamically added delete button with each input field. But I am unable to correctly delete the input fields.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 2;

  $(function() {
    $("#new_addButton,#addButton").bind("click", Add);
  });

  function Add() {
    if (counter > 15) {
      $('.not_more_than_fifteen').show();
      alert(counter);
      return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('li')).attr("id", 'job_responsibility' + counter);
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="text" class="new_highlight high_light" placeholder="Enter job responsibility" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" ><span class="remove_me"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo(".new_highlight");
    counter++;
    $(".remove_me").on("click", Delete);
  }

  function Delete() {
    alert(counter);
    $(this).parent().remove();
    counter = counter - 1;
    console.log(counter)
    return false;
  }
});
```

```
<ul class="new_highlight">
    <li><input class="form-control high_light" placeholder="" value="Driven and motivated individual who thrives in a dynamic and evolving environment." type="text"></li>
    <li><input class="form-control high_light" placeholder="" value="Basic understanding of TCP/IP and Internet-facing firewalls." type="text"><span class="remove_me"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span></li>
    <li><input class="form-control high_light" placeholder="" value="Minimum of five years of Linux and Windows administration" type="text"><span class="remove_me"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span></li>
    <li><input class="form-control high_light" placeholder="" value="Experience in configuration and troubleshooting of Tomcat server engine" type="text"><span class="remove_me"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span></li>
</ul>
<div class="">
   <span class="pull-left btn-add" id="addButton">Add More Responsibilities</span>
    <span class="not_more_than_fifteen pull-right">You have already added 15 rows!</span>
     <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to do **`event delegation`** for dynamically added `elements`. Could you also please add relevant `html`

Comment: You've any **console errors** in the browser?

Comment: Your code **[looks fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7wzry4pw/1/)** bdw..

Comment: Your `input` elements have the class of `new_highlight`, so you're appending new `li` elements to the previously added `input`... which makes no sense. It would really be a benefit to see your HTML here. Also, event delegation would help a lot here as @GuruprasadRao mentioned.

Comment: thanks event delegation worked for me @GuruprasadRao

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan event delegation worked for me

Comment: Good the hear that.. Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is bit confusing and has unnecessary codes in it. My solutuion is this;

HTML

```
<button id="add">add</button>
```

JS

```
var counter=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add').click(function(){
    if(counter<15){
    var inp = document.createElement('input');
    var del = document.createElement('button');
    $(del).addClass('delete');
    $(del).attr('onclick','remove(this)');
    $(del).text('delete');
    $('#add').after(inp);
    $('#add').after(del);
    $('#add').after('<br>');
    counter++;
    }
  });
});

function remove(e){
  $(e).next('input').remove();
  $(e).prev('br').remove();
  $(e).remove();
  counter--;
}
```

And the [**DEMO**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=c8325503f8c7d48e208d39ae8b67c86b)